# How to parse an invalid date with lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate

I need to parse dates and have a cases like "31/02/2018":

```
library(lubridate)
> dmy("31/02/2018", quiet = T)
[1] NA
```

This makes sense as the 31st of Feb does not exist. Is there a way to parse the string "31/02/2018" to e.g. 2018-02-28 ? So not to get an NA, but an actual date?

Thanks.

Comment: No, there isn't (because it is not an actual date). You can subset and replace it.

Comment: Is this a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @RuiBarradas So what is the X in your opinion?

Comment: To have those values recorded or somwhow show up .

Comment: @RuiBarradas blame the one, who filled the survey... or the one who did not set up a format filter. your choice. ;)

Comment: OK, not solvable at the source :(. But solvable, there's already an accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function assuming you would only have dates which could be higher than the actual date and would have the same format always.

```
library(lubridate)

get_correct_date <- function(example_date) {
  #Split vector on "/" and get 3 components (date, month, year)
  vecs <- as.numeric(strsplit(example_date, "\\/")[[1]])

  #Check number of days in that month
  last_day_of_month <-  days_in_month(vecs[2])

  #If the input date is higher than actual number of days in that month
  #replace it with last day of that month
  if (vecs[1] > last_day_of_month)
    vecs[1] <- last_day_of_month

  #Paste the date components together to get new modified date
  dmy(paste0(vecs, collapse = "/"))
}


get_correct_date("31/02/2018")
#[1] "2018-02-28"

get_correct_date("31/04/2018")
#[1] "2018-04-30"

get_correct_date("31/05/2018")
#[1] "2018-05-31"
```

With small modification you can adjust the dates if they have different format or even if some dates are smaller than the first date.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I also checked last_day_of_month for NA as some dates even had a faulty month and could not be recovered.

Comment: @c0bra I think month would need a separate treatment. This works only for dates. You can add a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some base solutions:

**1)** Use read.table to separate the parts into V1, V2 and V3 and then create the date at the start of the month.  To that subtract one and add the day.  for the example in the question it is 31 days from the last day of the prior month.

```
d <- c("30/02/2008", "31/02/2008", "15/02/2008")

d2 <- d |> read.table(text = _, sep = "/") |>
  with(as.Date(sprintf("%d-%02d-01", V3, V2)) - 1 + V1) 
d2
## [1] "2008-03-01" "2008-03-02" "2008-02-15"
```

**2)** If the end of the month (eom) is wanted when invalid then calculate the Date in the ordinary way and also the first day of the month (fom) and from that the end of month (eom) by adding 31 to fom, adding 31 to get to the next month, using cut to get the first of that month and subtracting 1 to get the end of the month of interest.  The date calculated in the ordinary way will be NA if invalid so the eom of month will be picked up by pmin.

```
d <- c("30/02/2008", "31/02/2008", "15/02/2008")

fom <- d |> sub("..", "01", x = _) |> as.Date(format = "%d/%m/%Y")
eom <- as.Date(cut(fom + 31, "month")) - 1
pmin(as.Date(d, "%d/%m/%Y"), eom, na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] "2008-02-29" "2008-02-29" "2008-02-15"
```